# Refer to opened workbook in different Excel Application

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set a reference to another workbook, that is already opened, in another Excel application. I can already set a reference to the other workbook when it is opened in the same application using

```
Set wbBOS = Application.Workbooks("wb2.xlsm")
```

This works because Application.Workbooks can find "wb2.xlsm". However if I open another instance of Excel and use the same line, it obviously does not find it within Application.Workbooks.

How can I set a reference to wb2 in that case?

EDIT: Given I know the full path, I can apparently set a reference to another application using :

```
 Set wbBOS =GetObject(path)
```

However I still get errors using Application functions such as

```
With wbBOS.Sheets("BOS")        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
```

Where it works fine if it is open in the same Application. How can I solve this?

Comment: As long as you know the full path, you can use `GetObject("path to workbook")`

Comment: As in `Set wbBOS =GetObject(path)` ?

Comment: Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32312737/1652222) link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How getObject Function internally works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304831/how-getobject-function-internally-works)

Comment: @DavidG Yes, like that.

Comment: @Rory Please see the EDIT in my question

Comment: Use `wbBOS.Application` rather than just `Application`