# Error running Excel Macro VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Running a job from AutoSys and I am getting an error.
VBS runs an excel macro. 
VBS code :

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error Resume Next
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Confidential Restricted\Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro.xlsm",0, False)
xlApp.Run "Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro.Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro"
xlBook.Close True
xlApp.Quit

set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'Excel.Application'
```

Comment: As stated in @ManishChristian's answer, the `CreateObject` syntax is wrong in your code. This leads to the error. And even if you offer a bounty of +1000000000 there is no other answer possible until you are correcting the syntax and tell us the error which is thrown using the correct syntax.

Comment: As stated in my response I had been using correct syntax but in attempt to resolve the error I made the change. I have edited the code in my question to what I now have and I am still recieving an error. Please see edited question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405937/active-x-error-with-excel-2016-and-late-binding#comment70015740_41405937. Try `CreateObject("Excel.Application.16")` or `CreateObject("Excel.Application.15")` or `.14` or `.12` dependent of your  Excel version. See http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win012.htm.

Comment: I tried this and got the following error  Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'Excel.Application.15' Looks to be the same issue?

Comment: Have you checked whether the registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application` and/or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application.15` exists?

Comment: I eventually found that the machine that was being used by the Autosys job does not have Microsoft Office installed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the script runs on my machine, it would not run on the machine that the AutoSys job was using. I eventually found that the machine that was being used by the Autosys job does not have Microsoft Office installed.

Answer (score 2):

You are using **`GetObject`** syntax with **`CreateObject`** method. You need to use:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Check [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312737/1652222) answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I had been using Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") originally, and that's when I got the error. This also doesn't work for me

Comment: First check the answer from the link that I've shared. If your Workbook is already open than use `GetObject`, but if Workbook is closed use `CreateObject`. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Workbook is closed. The error I am getting with this code is Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'Excel.Application'

Comment: This one is different error and for that you must allow system access.In your macro module at right down of screen you should choose allow system access.

Comment: I can't see this option? Could you explain in more detail how to do this?

Comment: Try: `Open Excel -> Excel optios -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings ->Macro Settings(from Trust Center window) -> Check Trust access to the VBA project object model`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137769/discussion-between-manishchristian-and-e-mcandrew).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetObject("Excel.Application"), but you need to make sure you open up an instance of excel before you use it.  GetObject will get a reference to this open instance of Excel and let you use that.