# VBscript select browser window and submit form

Tags: dom, vbscript

We have a single sign on product that launches a browser application and logs in. The user is then presented with a location select screen but I want to automate this too.

The SSO product allows us to customise with VBS, and I'm fairly certain I've got the code I need (populate hidden fields then submit the form).

Is it possible to use VBScript executed by WSH to interact with the DOM of a browser window and submit a form? The browser is already launched by the SSO product, so I'm looking to interact with a browser window that is already open.

Comment: You need to use [**`GetObject`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312737/1652222) function...

Comment: Thanks @ManishChristian, unfortunately that doesn't work because IE doesn't register itself with the ROT.